# How to compare CSV file in powershell but exclude some fields of the dataset within the compare

Tags: powershell, csv, compareobject

I'm looking for a way to compare two CSV files with powershell and output only the data sets from the first given CSV file which are different.
It should also be possible to exclude some fields of the data set (provided via the header field name of the CSV).

CSV example (First CSV file)

```
FirstName;LastName;LastUpdate;Mail;City;PostalCode
Max;Mustermann;01.01.2023;test@test.de;Musterstadt;12345
Maxi;Musterfrau;01.01.2022;maxi@test.de;Musterstadt;12345
```

CSV example (second CSV file)

```
FirstName;LastName;LastUpdate;Mail;City;PostalCode
Max;Mustermann;24.12.2023;test@test.de;Musterdorf;54321
Maxi;Musterfrau;12.12.2022;maxi@test.de;Musterstadt;12345
```

As shown in the CSV examples, the first dataset in CSV file 1 and 2 are different.
Now, within the compare process, the field 'LastUpdate' should be ignored, so that only the fields 'FirstName;LastName;Mail;City;PostalCode' will be used for comparing the data.

The return of the compare should be only the full datasets which are different and only from file one in a array.

I tried some different things but nothing works as expected.
Here a sample of my tries

```
# Define the file paths
$file1 = "..\file1.csv"
$file2 = "..\file2.csv"

# Read the first file into a variable
$data1 = Import-Csv $file1

# Read the second file into a variable
$data2 = Import-Csv $file2

# Compare the files, ignoring data from the 'LastUpdate' field 
$differences = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $data1 -DifferenceObject $data2 -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent -Property 'LastUpdate' | Where-Object {$_.SideIndicator -eq '<='} 

# export differences to a CSV file
$differences | Export-Csv -Path "..\Compare_result.csv" -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation
```

I hope you guys can help me out.
I thank you in advance

Comment: Given the data you've shown, I would expect `Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $data1 -DifferenceObject $data2 -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent -Property 'LastUpdate'` to not return anything (because the `LastUpdate` values are all different). What exactly were you expecting? If you want to output _differences_, then remove `-ExcludeDifferent`

Comment: You might try this [`Join-Object script`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Join)/[`Join-Object Module`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/JoinModule): `Import-Csv $file1 |OuterJoin (Import-Csv $file2) -on FirstName,LastName,Mail,City,PostalCode | Export-Csv -Path ..\Compare_result.csv`

Answer (score 1):

[`Compare-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/compare-object) doesn't allow you to *exclude* properties to compare by - **any properties you want to compare by must be expressed *positively***, as an array of names **passed to `-Property`**.

The purpose of the `-ExcludeDifferent` switch is to *exclude objects that compare differently* and only makes sense in combination with `-IncludeEqual`, given that objects that compare as equal are *not* included by default (in PowerShell (Core) 7+, use of `-ExcludeDifferent` now *implies* `-IncludeEqual`).

If `-Property` is used, the `[pscustomobject]` output objects have *only* the specified properties. **To pass the input objects through as-is**, the **`-PassThru` switch** must be used.

- The passed-through objects are decorated with an [ETS (Extended Type System)](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/6763) `.SideIndicator` property, so that filtering based on what side they were unique to is still possible.
- **Caveat**:  if `-IncludeEqual` is also present, for a given pair of input objects that compare equal, it is (only) the `-ReferenceObject` collection's object that is passed through - even though the `-DifferenceObject` object may have differing values in properties that *aren't* being compared.

Therefore:

```bash
# Compare the files, ignoring data from the 'LastUpdate' field 
$differences = 
  Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $data1 `
                 -DifferenceObject $data2 `
                 -Property FirstName, LastName, Mail, City, PostalCode `
                 -PassThru | 
  Where-Object SideIndicator -eq '<='
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my issue.
I forgot the Delimiter param for the two Import-csv, since the Delimiter in my CSV is a ;

So I changed from this code

```
# Read the first file into a variable
$data1 = Import-Csv $file1

# Read the second file into a variable
$data2 = Import-Csv $file2
```

to this code

```
# Read the first file into a variable
$data1 = Import-Csv $file1 -Delimiter ";"

# Read the second file into a variable
$data2 = Import-Csv $file2 -Delimiter ";"
```

After that I got the expected results from the compare.